# How to send a custom message with payload from Bot to Client application via directline?

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, direct-line-botframework

Here is my code where i am trying to send a custom message from bot to client application via `directline`. But through this i am able to receive the payload or text.

```
 var msg = new botbuilder.Message(session).sourceEvent({
         directline: {

              text:'Creating a note named '+note.title+ 'with description as '+ note.text,
              payload:{
                  action: "CREATENOTE"
              }   
         }                             

    });
    session.endDialog(msg);
```

On client side i am getting below `Activity` response:

```
   { type: 'endOfConversation',
  id: '6WYDh0QKiy31ij05UbsQgV|0000006',
  timestamp: '2018-04-09T05:18:23.2532985Z',
  localTimestamp: '2018-04-09T05:18:23.164+00:00',
  channelId: 'directline',
  from: { id: 'SarthakNotesBot', name: 'SarthakNotesBot' },
  conversation: { id: '6WYDh0JKiy31ij05UasQgV' },
  replyToId: '6WYDh0QKiy31ij05UasQgV|0000004',
  code: 'unknown' }
```

The `Activity` response say's `code:unknown`

Not sure how to make this work on directline.

Comment: I am unable to replicate similar output to what you are getting with your provided code sample...  which version of the NodeJS botbuilder framework are you using?  Also, is there any other surrounding code you can provide?

Comment: @BlackSeraph please check my answer. FYI, i am using node v6.9.1 and Bot Builder v3.13.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it like below:

```
 var msg = new builder.Message(session).entities([
     {  action: "CREATENOTE",
        payload: "other payload" 
        }   
    ])
    .text('Creating note named '+note.title+ ' with note description as  '+ note.text);       

    session.endDialog(msg);
```

Check below how can we create custom messages in BOT:

```
  var customMessage = new builder.Message(session)
    .text("Hello!")
    .textFormat("plain")
    .textLocale("en-us");
     session.send(customMessage);
```

For more information visit the official Microsoft docs: [Create Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-message-create)